# apply different functions to each element of a Perl data structure

Tags: json, perl

Given an arbitrarily nested data structure, how can I create a new data structure so that all the elements in it have been *standardized* by applying a function on all the elements depending on the type of the element. For example, I might have

```
$data = {
    name => 'some one',
    date => '2010-10-10 12:23:45',
    sale => [34, 22, 65],
    cust => {
        name => 'Jimmy',
        addr => '1 Foobar Way',
        amnt => 452.024,
        item => ['books', 'pens', 'post-it notes']
    }
}
```

and I want to convert all text values to upper case, all dates to UTC date times, find the square of all integers, round down all real numbers and add 1, and so on. So, in effect, I want to apply a different function to each element depending on the type of element.

In reality the data might arrive via a database query, in which case they are already a Perl data structure, or they might start life as a JSON object, in which case I can use `JSON::from_json` to convert it to a Perl data structure. The idea is to *standardize* all the values in the data structure based on the value type, and then spit out the Perl data structure back again as a JSON object.

I read [the answers to executing a function on every element of a data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375300/how-can-i-execute-a-given-function-on-every-element-of-a-complicated-data-struct) and feel that Data::Rmap might do the trick, but can't figure out how. <strike>Seems like Rmap works on all the **keys** as well, not just the **values**.</strike>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's crazy straightforward with [Data::Rmap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aRmap) you mentioned.

```
use Data::Rmap qw( rmap );
rmap { $_ = transform($_); } $data;
```

---

Regarding the question in the comments:

```
use Data::Rmap   qw( rmap );
use Scalar::Util qw( looks_like_number );

# Transforms $_ in place.
sub transform {
   if (looks_like_number($_)) {
      if (...) {
         $_ *= 2;
      }

      $_ = 0+$_;  # Makes it look like a number to JSON::XS
   } else {
      ...
   }
}

&rmap(\&transform, $data);
```

Comment: yes, it almost works. It seems to quote all the numbers, treating them like strings. So the string transformation works fine, but the numbers are not affected. Give a simple transform like `if ($data =~ /\d+/) { return $data * 2; }`, I get back **'34'** instead of **68**

Comment: @punkish, No, *you* are treating them as strings. The match operator matches against a string.

Comment: hmmm... I didn't know that. So, how do I ensure the numbers are treated as numbers and not coerced into strings, while strings remains strings? I want to do the right thing by **34** (convert it to **68**) or **35.03** (convert it to **36**) while leaving **'34'** and **'35.03'** alone.

Comment: @punkish, Appriately placed uses of `$_ = 0+$_;` will do it.